# How do I make a php page that reads different selections for different users?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a MySQL that lists about 500 items.  Users can register at the site and mark which item they have already.  This is a simple php that reads the table and each row.

How should I structure the database so that each user can have a particular setting for each item?

So that when Bob opens his account, he sees he already has ITEM 1, but when Mary opens it, she'll have ITEM 1 as missing and she can see who has that ITEM 1 twice or more times so that she may contact whoever has more than 1 of an item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Have a table that shows which users have what items...

Table Name: `user_items`

```
primary_key | user_id | item_number
-----------------------------------
     1      |    1    |     1
     2      |    1    |     1
     3      |    1    |     2
     4      |    2    |     2
```

or you could have something like this

```
primary_key | username | item_number
-----------------------------------
     1      |    bob   |     1 
     2      |    bob   |     1
     3      |    bob   |     2
     4      |    mary  |     2
```

This table above shows that:

User 1 / Bob has:

- item 1 x2
- item 2

User 2 / Mary has:

- item 2

Comment: Thanks Arian, thats exactly the sort of model I was looking for.  Its great to find helpful people like yourself in these sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can create other table with three columns, foreign key for item, foreign key for user and amount of that item.
You will keep there information that Bob has ITEM 1.